# Store the output of grep command in a file

Tags: linux, grep

I have a scp file that contains the paths to the various audio files. Say the scp file is `file.wav.scp` and it contains these paths

```
/home/red/audio1.wav
/home/blue/audio2.wav
/home/red/audio3.wav
/home/blue/audio4.wav
/home/blue/audio5.wav
```

I am using the `grep "blue" file.wav.scp` to find the paths which has the `blue` keyword in it. Now is there any way to store these outputs in a file directly from `grep's` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep "blue" file.wav.scp >outputfile`.

This is called [I/O redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) and is an essential concept in shell usage and programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep "blue" file.wav.scp > blue_file_paths.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
grep "blue" file.wav.scp > filename.txt
```